# Does Maven Central have correct mybatis-3.1.1 artifacts?

Tags: java, mybatis

I have configured mybatis dependencies in my pom.xml as follows:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
<artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

As per MyBatis documentation http://www.mybatis.org/core/statement-builders.html I tried to build Dynamic SQL query using org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.SQL class instead of using SelectBuilder/SqlBuilder classes.

But the mybatis-3.1.1.jar that is downloaded from Maven Central doesn't have org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.SQL.java class at all. Then I downloaded mybatis-3.1.1-bundle.zip from mybatis website and mybatis-3.1.1.jar in that bundle also doesn't have SQL.java.

I could find that SQL.java class in their source repository : http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/jdbc/?r=5407

Is org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.SQL.java class part of mybatis-3.1.1.jar or will be part of next release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [seems](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/source/detail?r=5407&path=/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/jdbc/SQL.java) the class you are searching for has been added on Sep 7, 2012; while myBatis-3.1.1 was released on Apr 15, 2012.

Comment: For additional details : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mybatis-user/DnZsvRA9VjI